Unable to create Timer instance when writing tests
I have the following Java code
    public void histogram(final String metricType,  final Tags tags, final long startTime) {
        long responseTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        Timer t = Timer.builder(metricType)
                .publishPercentileHistogram()
                .tags(tags)
                .serviceLevelObjectives(
                        Duration.ofMillis(400),
                        Duration.ofMillis(600),
                        Duration.ofMillis(1000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(2000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(5000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(15000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(20000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(30000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(60_000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(120_000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(180_000),
                        Duration.ofMillis(240_000))
                .maximumExpectedValue(Duration.ofMillis(240_000))
                .register(this.meterRegistry);
        t.record(Duration.ofMillis(responseTimeMillis));

I have a junit test that I want to write for the above method which looks like below
    void durationMetricHistogramTest() {
        Tags tags = Tags.of("k", "v");
        MeterRegistry.Config config = mock(MeterRegistry.Config.class);
        PauseDetector pauseDetector = mock(PauseDetector.class);
        when(meterRegistry.config()).thenReturn(config);
        when(meterRegistry.config().pauseDetector()).thenReturn(pauseDetector);
        metricsService.histogram("some_duration", tags, System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);

    

When I launch the Junit test, I get the below error
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.micrometer.core.instrument.Timer.record(java.time.Duration)" because "t" is null

Basically, when I write the test using mocks as above, Timer instance in my actual code class is coming out as null. I tried tracing the micrometer code but not much luck.
